# Sheep it renderfarm for 32 bit?

Tags: sheepit

I want to install the sheep it render farm client, but I have a 32 bit windows. So, is there a 32 bit client for sheep it? If not, can an emulator be used at least?  want to download the client, render projects and earn rankings. I also cannot use java as I use Chrome , which stopped supporting java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use their .jar file https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com/media/applet/client-latest.php and use your local java, it will work on 32bits.
The .exe is simply a java virtual machine and this file put together.